# NSInternalInconsistencyException on RootViewController

Tags: ios, navigation, tableview

I'm trying to create a navigation-stype app, but I want to customize the initial view so that the tableview doesn't occupy the entire frame, but rather is embedded within a sub-view so I can some labels and an image when the app is first launched.

I declared `UIView` and `UITableView` ivars in `RootViewController.h`, and added them both as properties with the standard "`(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet`" tokens; and in `RootViewController.m`, I synthesized both, and added code to set them to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`, and released them in `dealloc`. (Trying to be a good memory-management citizen.) I haven't added any other code. No warnings on the compile. When I tried to test-drive the app, it crashed immediately (and repeatedly) with the message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception                                       

NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the
"RootViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

I have connected both the view and the tableview to the File's Owner in my `RootViewController` nib; when I right-click on File's Owner in the object graph, I see both of them listed as Outlets. When I right-click each control, I see File's Owner as the Referencing Outlet.

Help! How do I fix this?

**Update**

```
//
//  RootViewController.m
//  rx2
//

#import "RootViewController.h"


@implementation RootViewController

/* I added these two lines */
@synthesize uiView;
@synthesize uiTableView;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;

/* I added these two lines */
    self.uiView = nil;
    self.uiTableView = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {

/* I added these two lines */
    [uiView release];
    [uiTableView release];


    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: I merged your answer into your question, you might want to edit the preface. Please do not post replies as answers, and consider taking the advice that the community gives you :)

Comment: I posted the reply as an answer, because I was unable to post a reply. What is the advice that I am being given? I have checked and rechecked the nib file, and all of the properties are connected to File's Owner. So what is the next step to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What this means is that the RootViewController's `view` property (inherited from `UIViewController`) isn't connected to a view in the nib file. If you right click the File's Owner in the object graph, so you see it's `view` outlet connected to a view in the layout as in the attached screenshot?

[image: the file's owner's view property connected to a view]

Can you post your RootViewController.h file as an edit to your question?

Comment: Yes, I see the connections as follows:

Comment: File's Owner has Outlets listed for my instance variable properties as well for a view property; they all have the circle filled in. (Sorry, I can't seem to cut and paste the image the way you did)...

Comment: How did you embed the File's Owner graphic on this page? I took a snapshot (command+shift+3 / 4), but I can't insert it...

Comment: Images aren't supported in comments...Well somewhere there's a disconnect here, and it's hard to tell without seeing your project files. Can you post your RootViewController's m file in your question?

Comment: You can add an image to your question. There's a little polaroid icon above the text edit box that allows you to do so. I'd post a screenshot of it, but…

Comment: are you talking about the text-exit application on the mac?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to connect the default view in xib to the file owner.

Comment: When I look at File's Owner in the RootViewController.xib file, the circle for outlet is filled in

Comment: look at the view is connected or not and if it is connected then disconnect it and connect again