# Terminating app due to uncaught exception

Tags: ios4, xcode4

I am getting the following error when i start my app on simulator

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'RootViewController''

Please tell me how i can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've probably renamed or removed RootViewController, and your MainWindow.xib is still looking for it.

have a look on this SO question:
[NSInternalInconsistencyException on RootViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418869/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-on-rootviewcontroller)

if you are still stuck a quick Google of "nsinternalinconsistencyexception rootviewcontroller" may shed some light

Comment: Thanks for helping. I got my mistake.I didn't changed the nib file name in MainWindow.xib file to the one i want to call. Fixed now

Comment: @codejunkie No worries mate :). remember to close off the question by marking an answer as correct, or write your own if you figure it out yourself :)